# How can Read data from URL without using cURL or file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I am using a Jabong browser call to fetch the product information data from there without using cURL & file_get_contents but unfortunately, I don't found any way to get the data. can anyone help on this?

Here is the URL: https://www.jabong.com/product/offers?styleId=4583165

Comment: What's the problem with curl or file_get_contents?

Comment: There is way with cURL or file_get_contents. What else you want to use?

Comment: "without using cURL & file_get_contents" — You're rejecting the two standard ways with no explanation as to why. What is wrong with them? Why would anything else someone might suggest not have the same problem?

Comment: Can you please help me to extract the data from them because i can't do it?

Comment: @NigSysTechnologies — When people ask for clarification about your problem, it usually helps to *answer them* instead of providing an information-free appeal for help. People are already looking at your question and trying to help. You aren't making it easy for them.

Comment: $request_url= "https://www.jabong.com/product/offers?styleId=3239867";

$headers   = array(); 
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curl),TRUE);
curl_close($curl);

Comment: Please look into it what is wrong in it?

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, edit the question and put the code there. Also, please add information about how the code you posted fails.

Comment: @NigSysTechnologies — You can edit your question (and use the code formatting tools) to add more information in a readable fashion. You could also give us a more detailed description of the problem than "something wrong"

Answer (score -1):

i think your really problem with data after fetch it

your link https://www.jabong.com/product/offers?styleId=4583165 
return json string so you should use json_decode to convert it to  Array/Object (stdClass) so you can read data